Yii2 Module loading, but 404 with every route in this module
In my yii2 project I added a new module 'v2' (mirror of v1 + the new changes - v1 running great). Of course I replaced all v1 with v2 and checked for the correct cases.
I registered the module in the web.php:
'bootstrap' => [ 'log', 'v1', 'v2'],
'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'class' => api\modules\v1\ApiV1Module::class,
            'controllerNamespace' => 'api\modules\v1\controllers',
        ],
        'v2' => [
            'class' => api\modules\v2\ApiV2Module::class,
            'controllerNamespace' => 'api\modules\v2\controllers',
        ],
],

The url Manager in web.php looks like that:
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],

The routes are defined in the module class: ApiV2Module.php:
    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        
        \Yii::info("ApiV2Module is bootstrapping", __METHOD__);
        
        \Yii::info("Incoming request to: " . \Yii::$app->request->url, __METHOD__);
        
        $app->getUrlManager()->addRules([
            '/v2/user/<id:\d+>' => '/v2/user/index',
            '/v2/friends/<id:\d+>' => '/v2/friends/index',
            '/v2/challenge/<id:\d+>' => '/v2/challenge/index',
            '/v2/challenge/<id:\d+>/<action>' => '/v2/challenge/<action>',
            '/v2/exercises/<id:\d+>' => '/v2/exercises/index',
            '/v2/exercises/<id:\d+>/<action>' => '/v2/exercises/<action>',
            '/v2/notifications/<page:\d+>' => '/v2/notifications/index',
            '/v2/notifications/<_a>' => '/v2/notifications/<_a>',
            '/v2/user/goals/<id:\d+>' => '/v2/user/goals',
            '/v2/user/exp/<id:\d+>' => '/v2/user/exp',
        ]);
    }

Te UserController is properly defined and the methods are properly named:
<?php namespace api\modules\v2\controllers;

use api\components\Controller;
use api\modules\v2\models\User\UserInfoModel;
use api\modules\v2\models\User\UserUpdateModel;
use api\modules\v2\models\User\UserDeleteModel;
use api\modules\v2\actions\User\DashboardAction;

use api\modules\v2\models\UserGoalsModel;
use api\modules\v2\models\UserLevelExpModel;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($id = null)
    {
        \Yii::info("Entering actionIndexV2 with ID: $id", __METHOD__);
        if ($this->request->isGet) {
            return $this->processActionModel(
                new UserInfoModel([
                    'user_id' => $id,
                    'logged_user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->id,
                ]),
            );

        } else if ($this->request->isPatch) {
            return $this->processActionModel(
                new UserUpdateModel([ 'user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->id ]),
            );
        } else if ($this->request->isDelete) {
            return $this->processActionModel(
                new UserDeleteModel([ 'user_id' => $id ]),
            );
        }
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        \Yii::info("Actions method called in UserController V2", __METHOD__);
        return [
            'dashboard' => DashboardAction::class,
        ];
    }
    
    // Fetch and update goals
    public function actionGoals($id)
    {
        \Yii::info("Entering actionGetGoals with ID: $id", __METHOD__);
        $model = new UserGoalsModel(['user_id' => $id]);
        return $this->processActionModel($model);
    }

    public function actionUpdateGoals($id)
    {
        \Yii::info("Entering actionUpdateGoals with ID: $id", __METHOD__);
        $model = new UserGoalsModel(['user_id' => $id]);
        $newGoals = \Yii::$app->request->post('goals');
        return $model->updateGoals($newGoals);
    }

    // Fetch and update level and exp
    public function actionExp($id)
    {
        \Yii::info("Entering actionGetLevelExp with ID: $id", __METHOD__);
        $model = new UserLevelExpModel(['user_id' => $id]);
        return $this->processActionModel($model);
    }

    public function actionUpdateLevelExp($id)
    {
        \Yii::info("Entering actionUpdateLevelExp with ID: $id", __METHOD__);
        $model = new UserLevelExpModel(['user_id' => $id]);
        $newLevel = \Yii::$app->request->post('level');
        $newExp = \Yii::$app->request->post('exp');
        return $model->updateLevelExp($newLevel, $newExp);
    }
}


In the example of the call: url/v2/user/get-level-exp/id
the model then looks like this:
<?php

namespace api\modules\v2\models\User;

use yii\base\Model;
use app\models\User;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

class UserLevelExpModel extends Model
{
    public int $user_id;

    public function process(): mixed
    {
        $user = User::findOne($this->user_id);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("User not found");
        }

        return [
            'level' => $user->level,
            'exp' => $user->exp,
        ];
    }

    public function updateLevelExp($newLevel, $newExp): bool
    {
        $user = User::findOne($this->user_id);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("User not found");
        }

        $user->level = $newLevel;
        $user->exp = $newExp;
        return $user->save();
    }
}


The log ApiV2Module is bootstrapping shows.
Modules loaded log in web.php shows as well with v2 inside.
But still with every endpoint I am testing with postman regarding v2 I get a 404 error.
I have no more idea where the problem could be.
At this point I just want to save this haha
Thanks a lot!
Tried to call the endpoint: url/v2/user/get-level-exp/63 - expected some response other than 404, but got a 404

But you dont have such route defined, the only one i see is '/v2/user/exp/<id:\d+>'

Try to call on this end point and see what it does

In this case 404 from Yii is reasonable, because this route (url/v2/user/get-level-exp/id) is not defined in the route list
